# Web Audio AnalyserNode returns empty data

Tags: javascript, audio, web

HTML:

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="song.mp3" oncanplay="done(this)"></audio>
```

JS:

```
function done(audio) {

    var ctx = new AudioContext();

    var audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    var analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();

    audioSrc.connect(analyser);
    audioSrc.connect(ctx.destination);

    var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);

    console.log(array);

}
```

All that is written to the console is an array of all zeroes. Anybody know what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Do you ever start your audio ? Also are you trying to log this only in the `oncanplay` event ? The values returned by getByteFrequencyData are relative to the data the analyser node has at the moment you called it. It is more than likely that at canplay event, no data has been passed to the analyser. You have to call it in a loop, check [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) for a working example that you can fiddle around.

Comment: Sorry, for the late response, but thanks for the help. Its working now. :)

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. You may then want to remove your question so it gets out of the *should be answered* stream, since it is unlikely to help anyone in the future.